# django-grappelli and chunks app

Tags: django

How to add TINY-MCE to chunks? I use django-grappelli

For standard models I use:

```
class DataAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass

    class Media:
        js = [
        '/static/grappelli/tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js',
        '/static/tinymce_setup.js',
        ]
```

and it work.

EDIT:

@Timmy O'Mahony solution work fine or just:

```
class CustomChunkAdmin(ChunkAdmin):
    class Media:
        js = [
        '/static/grappelli/tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js',
        '/static/tinymce_setup.js',
        ]
admin.site.unregister(Chunk)
admin.site.register(Chunk, CustomChunkAdmin)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In an existing admin file:

```
from django.db import models
from tinymce.widgets import TinyMCE
from chunks.admin import ChunkAdmin
from chunks.models import Chunk

class CustomChunkAdmin(ChunkAdmin):
    formfield_overrides = {
        models.TextField: {'widget': TinyMCE() },
    }
admin.site.unregister(Chunk)
admin.site.register(Chunk, CustomChunkAdmin)
```